# Threadding clients using a tcp listner

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

(Using vb 2008 express.)

I am trying to create a server to send clients text on request.
I am using a tcp listener to accept clients then send each client to a thread in a threadpool which deals with each client's request then closes the client connection.
It seems to work fine but I would like to know how it works.
Using the listen loop below I cant help feeling I should be sending some values to the threaded sub. How does it know which client each thread is dealing with?

```
Sub ListenLoop()

    Looop:

    Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf ClientThread))

    GoTo Looop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't unless you supply a state object to track which user it is.

Check out MSDN's article on Non-blocking TCP Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx